# Remove campaign member from Salesforce in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign, campaign-member

Is it possible to remove a campaign member from particular campaign using AMPscript? As far as I know there's no function like "DeleteSalesforceObject" (in contrary to CreateSalesforceObject). I'd like to remove members, whose status is "declined".

Answer (score 0):

If you want them deleted you need to create APEX trigger on Sales Cloud's side that deletes records with chosen status.